# Combining EC2 with S3 and RDS from AWS Amazon

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I would like opinions if the following scenario is feasible or not.  Also, if you think that I see something wrong don't hesitate to mention that.

I have to propose and create a System Architecture schema for a company that runs right now 3 different servers (different server providers) on 3 different locations and they host around 50++ website per server.

So, right now, it is like this:

- server1:

  - website1.com
  - website2.com
  - website3.com
  - website4.com
  - ....
- server2:

  - website21.com
  - website22.com
  - website23.com
  - website24.com
  - ....
- server3:

  - website31.com
  - website32.com
  - website33.com
  - website34.com
  - ....

Server1 has a big MySql database that every other server (server2,server3 and included server1) is using it with a remote mysql connection.

So,

MySQL server from server1 servers:

- server1 (locally)
- server2 (remotely)
- server3 (remotely)

Server1 under the domain website1.com has a folder with images that all the other websites on the servers, included the server1, must to access them.

For example:

website1.com  uses an image file image/image1.jpg, and the same time website2.com and website3.com uses the same image1.jpg  as   http://website1.com/image/image1.jpg

Also, every website on each server checks each time if the file exists. Actually the checking is done by php so, on the server side. They check if the image exist locally using `if_file_exist()` and remotely with `if (getheaders() ==200 )`

E.g.

If a visitor try to access the website1.com, the website1.com (actually the server1) checks `if website1.com/image/image1.jpg exists`. 
Also,
If a visitor try to access the website21.com, the website21 (actually the server2) checks `if header of http://website1.com/image/image1.jpg == 200` .

So,

The website1.com/image/image1.jpg on server1 accessed and checked if the image exists by all the websites:

- website1.com
- website2.com
- ....
- website21.com
- website22.com
- ....
- website31.com
- website32.com
- ....

In my opinion,

the best scenario probably can be the following:

3 AWS EC2 instances  as running server. 
1 AWS S3 bucket that has all the files on the /image/ folder
1 RDS database that servers all the websites that hosted in the 3 EC2 instances.

In that case,

one EC2 instance can get and check if the file exist from the S3 bucket, and the same EC2 instance will get the data on the database from the RDS.

If I am correct, the latency of from EC2 instance to check if file exists and get it from S3 should be really low because it should be "locally" though the AWS infrastructure.

and also, a query on the shared RDS should be faster and more secure due to the same reason.

So,

if a visitor access website1.com

we will have the following:

website1.com ->  EC1 instance

- html/php files from EC1
- get query data from the RDS
- get image data from the S3 bucket

website21.com ->  EC2 instance

- html/php files from EC2
- get query data from the RDS
- get image data from the S3 bucket

Is is a feasible scenario?  Or I see something wrong ?

Did you see any other option on that?

Another option:

By using instead of the S3  the Amazon CloudFront will it solve the problem quicker ?

**Edit**

The checking should be done because of the following:

image1.jpg   is an image.
and image1-es.jpg is a dedicated image for the specific  country ES (spain).

In other words, server should check there is an image dedicated for visitors from ES (spain), if not, server the general image.

Comment: I'd probably need to learn more about this application, but I'm curious as to why you need to check if the S3 image file is there, vs letting the client make a request to S3 directly?  Latency may be low because it's S3, but S3 isn't super fast in general.  You may consider having a background job go and periodically index the contents of the S3 bucket and shove the results into memcache or similar to speed things up a bit.

Comment: @WedgeMartin  I answered on the question and thanks for your comment.
Also, I think that only on the server-side that checking can be done. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @WedgeMartin Also, may the CloudFront help  to speed up the things ?

Comment: CloudFront typically speeds things up a bit, though keep in mind that updates to it can take quite a bit longer to propagate.

Answer (score 1):

You plan will likely work, but probably isn't optimal. S3 isn't a file system, so your applications may need to be rewritten to take advantage of it. There are pieces of software available that can make it look somewhat like a file system.

You might be better off using

- EC2 virtual machines
- EBS volume running just the operating system most likely. You could put some or all of the files to serve (static + PHP) on the EBS volume if you weren't concerned about sharing them with other instances.
- EFS (Elasic File System) to store shared files on. If you run Wordpress the whole Wordpress install can be on here - that way if you scale to multiple Ec2 instances running the same website your wp-content folder and such is shared, and you only have to maintain one Wordpress instance. Note this may still be in beta.
- CloudFront for CDN file delivery
- RDS for database

Serving region specific files is the responsibility of your software, and Amazon infrastructure.

Comment: So, If I can understand correct,

EC2 instance will have the html/php files, the EFS is attached to the EC2 and it contains the sharing folder with the images,  and RDS will have the database-data.
So, if a visitor hits the website1.com, the EC2 will get the files from the EFS ("locally") and the RDS ("locally") again.  And finally the EC2 will server the full web page to the visitor via the CloudFront. 

Right?

Comment: Can you please explain me why to have the WordPress installization on the EFS ?

Comment: Indeed, some of the websites are Wordpress, but they are the minority.  They only serve the other "custom frameworked"  websites with their feeds. Nothing more.   Where will it help to have the Wordpress install in the EFS ?

Comment: On my point of view the reason to have the WP installed into the EFS is to have several WP sites with one WP installation. The databases of the WPs will be on the RDS and the installation will be on the EFS.   Right?

There is a link on Reddit about WP + EFS: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/3trahr/wordpress_web_farm_using_elastic_file_system/

Comment: Answer expanded

Comment: EFS would absolutely be preferred over S3 for an application where the servers are accessing the files heavily like the question seems to suggest.  Of course, it seems like the application would be far better overall if the image link were always pointing to the localized image, with an image server (behind a cache) returning the localized image if available and the default image if not.  If -- as it sounds like -- the HTML is being rendered with image links whose targets are determined based on whether files exist, that sounds dreadfully inefficient and unnecessarily slow.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yep. I know that the checking (if image exist) every time is really inefficient. However, the case of doing this, is because images1.jpg can have a dedicate image for Spain, but not for Germany.  In that case, the developers can not point directly the image due to the country of the visitor, because for a German visitor for example it does not exist (so image1-de.jpg return a 404 error code and server has to server the default image1.jpg).  So, it has to be checked every time if there is an image dedicated for the visitors country.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot 2 points: 1) if you think in that case that I described above, there is an another option that should be great.  The only solution that I can think is to map for every country around the world the images in a DB. So, there would be only a query on that particular solution that checks if the image "lets say exists". 

2) I don't get why to have EBS first of all. I think that EBS is for backup purpuses.  Also, I don't really get why to have S3 and EBS together.  In any case, EBS should be faster rather the S3.

Comment: You said: "... on the EBS volume if you weren't concerned about sharing them with **other instances**."  Do you mean my instances on the VPC that the EC2 will belong, or all the EC2 in the region (even if they are not mine).  I think that EBS mounts only to me, and EBS is visible only to my VPC. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You need EBS (Elastic Block Store) because it provides the hard drive(s) for the instances.  EBS is very fast, but the data on an EBS volume is not accessible to any instance except the *one* instance to which it is attached, unless you make it accessible by exposing it with NFS or a web service.  This isn't a good way to share content, since the instance is a single point of failure.  EFS (elastic filesystem) is a managed filesystem that multiple instances can access simultaneously.  It is accessed using the NFS protocol but with layers of redundancy.

Comment: Regarding images, you link to image1-de.jpg.  You have an image web service that handles the request for image1-de.jpg.  If there is no such image, it would return the content of image1-global.jpg instead of a 404 error. This is pretty easily done with Varnish, using S3 or a web server for fetching the image content, and would seem to have a pretty dramatic potential for performance improvement since the application has no need to do lookups at all.  Caching by, or in front of, this service means it doesn't even have to continually look to see whether the files exist.

Comment: @john, I suggest you do an AWS course, either online or in person, to understand these concepts. It's difficult to describe architectural options in a question and answer format, and it's not what FS is for. If you need immediately help you may be best of hiring someone to assist you.